Connection Timeout Quarkus Vertex
When the input stream is of 7MB, the first API call after the build always fails and all the subsequent calls get successful. We get the below logs when the API fails. Sudden read timeout happens, but I could not figure out the reason and solution.
2023-12-18 23:18:11,768 WARNING 23 [com.log.cor.jax.imp.exc.map.BaseExceptionMapper] (50740c4dfeb9df41) createResponse(Throwable): java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: io.vertx.core.http.HttpClosedException: Connection was closed
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxInputStream$VertxBlockingInput.readBlocking(VertxInputStream.java:255)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxInputStream.readIntoBuffer(VertxInputStream.java:122)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxInputStream.read(VertxInputStream.java:84)
at java.base/java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:199)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream.fillBuffer(BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java:111)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.MimeBoundaryInputStream.fillBuffer(MimeBoundaryInputStream.java:223)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.MimeBoundaryInputStream.read(MimeBoundaryInputStream.java:157)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream.fillBuffer(BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java:111)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.BufferedLineReaderInputStream.read(BufferedLineReaderInputStream.java:158)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.io.LineReaderInputStreamAdaptor.read(LineReaderInputStreamAdaptor.java:67)
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.util.ContentUtil.copy(ContentUtil.java:55)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.AbstractStorageProvider.store(AbstractStorageProvider.java:57)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.storage.StorageBodyFactory.binaryBody(StorageBodyFactory.java:94)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.Mime4jWorkaroundBinaryEntityBuilder.body(Mime4jWorkaroundBinaryEntityBuilder.java:159)
at org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeStreamParser.parse(MimeStreamParser.java:133)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.Mime4JWorkaround.parseMessage(Mime4JWorkaround.java:83)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl.parse(MultipartInputImpl.java:104)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormAnnotationReader.readFrom(MultipartFormAnnotationReader.java:58)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:101)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:63)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:80)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:213)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:128)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: io.vertx.core.http.HttpClosedException: Connection was closed   

I tried to add vertex configuration but nothing worked.
